# skipping and merging similar data ecto elixir

Tags: jquery, elixir, chart.js, ecto

I have some records in the database and I am getting them as.

```
  def get_all_records_for_sim(sim_number) do
    SimLogs
    |> where(number: ^sim_number)
    |> order_by(asc: :datetime)
    |> Repo.all
    |> IO.inspect
  end
```

as a result, I get this kind of data,

```
 %EdgeCommander.ThreeScraper.SimLogs{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "sim_logs">,
  addon: "60GB Broadband", allowance: "61,440.00 MB",
  datetime: ~N[2017-10-12 10:39:00.839670], id: 795, name: "User 6 Sim",
  number: "0860100421", volume_used: "0.00 MB"},
 %EdgeCommander.ThreeScraper.SimLogs{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "sim_logs">,
  addon: "60GB Broadband", allowance: "61,440.00 MB",
  datetime: ~N[2017-10-12 11:02:20.296758], id: 815, name: "User 6 Sim",
  number: "0860100421", volume_used: "0.00 MB"},
 %EdgeCommander.ThreeScraper.SimLogs{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "sim_logs">,
  addon: "60GB Broadband", allowance: "61,440.00 MB",
  datetime: ~N[2017-10-13 05:30:25.800565], id: 837, name: "User 6 Sim",
  number: "0860100421", volume_used: "0.00 MB"},
 %EdgeCommander.ThreeScraper.SimLogs{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "sim_logs">,
  addon: "60GB Broadband", allowance: "61,440.00 MB",
  datetime: ~N[2017-10-16 05:24:04.536224], id: 859, name: "User 6 Sim",
  number: "0860100421", volume_used: "0.00 MB"},
 %EdgeCommander.ThreeScraper.SimLogs{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "sim_logs">,
  addon: "60GB Broadband", allowance: "61,440.00 MB",
  datetime: ~N[2017-10-16 12:28:21.565377], id: 881, name: "User 6 Sim",
  number: "0860100421", volume_used: "43.09 MB"},
 %EdgeCommander.ThreeScraper.SimLogs{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "sim_logs">,
  addon: "60GB Broadband", allowance: "61,440.00 MB",
  datetime: ~N[2017-10-17 05:03:49.866221], id: 903, name: "User 6 Sim",
  number: "0860100421", volume_used: "43.09 MB"}]
```

there are many duplicates are coming from it, which is not exactly the same but if you look at `DateTime`, the first part of the date is same as `2017-10-12` and `2017-10-16`, In above example, I am processing that data to furthermore to create a chart line as

```
chartjs_data =
  sim_number
  |> get_all_records_for_sim()
  |> Enum.map(fn(one_record) ->
    {current_in_number, _} = one_record |> get_volume_used() |> String.replace(",", "") |> Float.parse()
    {allowance_in_number, _} = one_record |> get_allowance() |> String.replace(",", "") |> Float.parse()

    %{
      datetime: "#{shift_datetime(one_record.datetime)}",
      percentage_used: (current_in_number / allowance_in_number * 100) |> Float.round(3)
    }
  end)
```

which results in an array of such objects `{percentage_used: 0, datetime: "2017-10-10 05:03:49"}`, My issue is, I want to merge the same dates, for example, if there are 7 records of `2017-10-12`, then make them one, and as the other half of the object is based on `volume_used`(ecto resulting query), so get the mean of all those 7 record's `volume_used` and make it one and create object as `{percentage_used: MEAN_OF_ALL_7_RECORDS, datetime: "2017-10-12"}`..

there are multiple ways of doing that, But I am looking if its possible in ecto, or on the server side only in any efficient way? any help would be appreciable.

UPDATE: Or maybe in if its possible in jquery as to process this data,

```
[{percentage_used: 0, datetime: "2017-10-10 05:03:49"}
{percentage_used: 0, datetime: "2017-10-10 17:13:38"}
{percentage_used: 0, datetime: "2017-10-11 04:39:32"}
{percentage_used: 0, datetime: "2017-10-11 12:50:42"}
{percentage_used: 0, datetime: "2017-10-12 06:31:22"}
{percentage_used: 0, datetime: "2017-10-12 09:21:08"}
{percentage_used: 0, datetime: "2017-10-12 09:34:33"}
{percentage_used: 0, datetime: "2017-10-12 10:17:00"}
{percentage_used: 0, datetime: "2017-10-12 10:39:00"}
{percentage_used: 0, datetime: "2017-10-12 11:02:20"}]
```

and making something like

```
[{percentage_used: 0, datetime: "2017-10-10"}
{percentage_used: 0, datetime: "2017-10-11"}
{percentage_used: 0, datetime: "2017-10-11"}]
```

any solution would be appreciable. thanks

Comment: Do you really need the mean of volume_used or is it better to fetch the last record for each unique day?

Comment: Yes you are right as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT ON date_trunc('day', datetime)` in the query to return only one record per day from the database:

```
SimLogs
|> where(number: ^sim_number)
|> distinct([s], fragment("date_trunc('day', ?)", s.datetime))
|> order_by(asc: :datetime)
|> Repo.all
```

To fetch the last record per day, you can to modify the `order_by`:

```
|> order_by([s], [asc: fragment("date_trunc('day', ?)", s.datetime), desc: s.datetime])
```

Comment: what `date_trunc` do here? out of interest?

Comment: also when we do distinct.. it fetches the very last record?

Comment: It'll truncate the datetime value upto that precision. So with `'date'` as the first argument, it'll set the hour/minute/second to 0. This makes the `distinct` clause remove duplicate records by just the date part of the datetime.

Comment: No, I believe it fetches the first record. In the data you've posted the rest of the fields are the same in all records. If you still want the last record per day, you can change the order by to descending and then do a `Enum.reverse` after `Repo.all`. (There's probably a better way to do this with JOINs.)

Comment: Yeah I am accepting the solution, But i was much interested for ecto query, for example if the last records was added at the end of the day, and first one start of the day, then It should get the distinct but the last added, may be am making words, But I Thought it this way..

Comment: I've edited my answer. Let me know if that order_by works correctly for you. It shouldn't require `Enum.reverse`.